# Servlet getting invoked twice when the content type is application/pdf

Tags: java, servlets

I have a servlet which copies the InputStream to the ServletOutputstream using the Apache IOUtils. The servlet is getting invoked twice. I have tested both on IE and Firefox. Did anybody encounter situation like this? Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the outgoing HTTP requests using Firebug in Firefox. Ensure that you understand how servlets and filters work and how the `url-pattern` in the mappings should be configured/interpreted. Either the browser did *actually* send two HTTP requests, or any servlet or filter has forwarded/redirected the request to the servlet in question. More can't I be of assistance based on the as far given little information.